# using GridLayout with android support package r8

Tags: android, layout

I install the android support package r8 and i want to use the `GridLayout` so here what i have tried so far in my xml file

```
<android.support.v4.widget.GridLayout>
```

but when i run the code it told me that no class found for `android.support.v4.widget.GridLayout` 
i opened the jar file and look in the packages there is no `GridLayout.class` file . any one knows how to use the `GridLayout` using the android support packages

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The support implementation of GridLayout is actually a library project which you need to include in your own project. It can be found in the Android sdk directory under extras/android/support/v7/gridlayout.

Also, you need to use `<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>` in your layouts.